# Extracting data from json response

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to get data from json response into my project but i end up getting more than i want. I am trying to get the value of "`price`" from this API that i am using  https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/convert/globalfrom=ZAR&to=BTC&amount=200000
which gives me the response

```
{
    "price": 1.13894342,
    "success": true,
    "time": "2017-12-25 23:47:27"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is extract just the 1.13894342 from the response how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: Feeding your title into Google gives 2.6 MILLION hits, 18,700 on this site alone.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Explain further please

Comment: Okay i have figured it out its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
dim yourJsonResponse as String = whateveryourfunctioniscalled()
dim yourJObject = JObject.Parse(yourJsonResponse)
dim priceValue = yourJObject("price")
```

Note that priceValue is just an Object , you have to convert the type by your own.